# Is there a way to rebuild fragmented indexes without filling up logs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms, database-administration

Is there a way I can rebuild or reorganize all fragmented indexes on Microsoft SQL Server without logs filling up my drive?

I tried setting up a maintenance plan but whenever the job starts logs fill up my server hard disk..

Is there any known way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: You can't prevent the system from using the logs. They are needed to support the [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) principal. There are some things you can do to help minimize log growth. Like smaller transactions. But with no real details about what your maintenance plans are, disc space etc there isn't much to go on here.

Comment: Which recovery model do you use?

Comment: @МаксимИванов I don't understand

Comment: @g33k3dallw33k Right click on YourDataBase -> Properties -> Options -> "Recovery model:". There are 3 options: Full, Bulk-logged, Simple. Which one is yours?

Comment: @МаксимИванов my db is using Simple Recovery model